# Execute function on a specific column

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

I have the following function that converts text to proper case:

```
USE [Messaging]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ProperCase]    Script Date: 10/28/2014 11:42:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER  Function [dbo].[ProperCase](@Text as varchar(8000))
 returns varchar(8000)
 as
 begin
    declare @Reset bit;
    declare @Ret varchar(8000);
    declare @i int;
    declare @c char(1);

    select @Reset = 1, @i=1, @Ret = '';

    while (@i <= len(@Text))
          select @c= substring(@Text,@i,1),
                @Ret = @Ret + case when @Reset=1 then UPPER(@c) else LOWER(@c) end,
                @Reset = case when @c like '[a-zA-Z]' then 0 else 1 end,
                @i = @i +1
    return @Ret
 end
```

The function works.  If I run `select dbo.propercase ('DOE, JOHN')`, the output will be "Doe, John".  That's exactly what I want.  The thing is, I want to run this function on the MailBoxName field in the Mailbox table.  How do I do that?

Comment: My suggestion: do this in the presentation tier. Also watch out for names like `Julio de la SanMarcos` and `Jean-Pierre le VanWyck III`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an update statement. This will run the dbo.propercase function against the MailBoxName field on the Mailbox table - which will update the MailBoxNames to propercase.

```
UPDATE Mailbox
SET MailBoxName = dbo.propercase(MailBoxName)
```

Comment: No problem @DelDunbar, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a select statement

```
select dbo.propercase (MailBoxName) as Proper
from Mailbox
```

Why was this a mystery?

Comment: Oh, I don't know.  Maybe because I didn't know how to do it!!  Most of us don't have 25+ years experience like you.

Comment: @DelDunbar - This would be in any documentation / book on using functions in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, dbo.propercase(MailBoxName) AS ProperCaseMailBoxName
FROM Mailbox
```